# coldfusion 2016 cfchart sizing issues

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cfchart

on a migration to Cold Fusion 2016 we are having issues with the charts.

We can generate the chart but the image is too small.
It looks like it is adding white space in the area.

can you control the size of the pie chart? 
We do need them created into png files since we are embedding into reports

[image: this is the image we get returned. we want a 200px by 200px chart]

Trying to get a 200px by 200px large pie chart .  the returned image is the correct size but the charts are tiny.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you could take the image and then send it to ColdFusion's image manipulation functions can get something that is cropped to your needs.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are using to generate the chart?

Comment: This problem exemplifies why using built in CF GUI tags is a bad idea in the long run. Decouple your GUI from CF and avoid this problem in the future. You could build your own chart GUI tags to simplify the refactor, depending on how dependent the code is on cfchart.

Comment: <cfchart showlegend="false" show3d="True"
name="clicks_pie" format="png" height="150" width="150"    chartheight ="150" chartwidth ="150">
<cfchartseries type="pie" seriescolor="##0000FF" datalabelstyle="none" paintstyle="plain" colorlist="#pie_colorlist#">
<cfloop query="tracking_typlist">
<cfchartdata value="#evaluate("Trackingtype_#Tracking_type_id#.clicks")#" item="#evaluate("Trackingtype_#Tracking_type_id#.name")#">   </cfloop>
</cfchartseries>
 </cfchart>